# How to toggle selected or clicked element not all

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to toggle only clicked element and adding some class to it but it's applying to all.
How can i do that?.any suggestion would be helpful.thank you

```js
$("li").click(function(e){
   $(".checkbox span").toggleClass("checked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    Wordz
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="secondary"></span>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    Phraser
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="secondary"></span>
    </label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to get current `li` clicked and depending on that add your class.

**Demo Code**:

```js
$("li").click(function(e) {
//cuurent li->span->addclass
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass("checked");
});
```

```css
.checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> Wordz
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="secondary">Something</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    Phraser
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="secondary">Something</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much it's working, i was looking exactly something like that..Cheers  have a good day

Comment: How long u have been working on Javascript? and how do u approach problems..

Comment: For your question i just saw you need to add class for the particular li which is clicked.and i was knowing for that you need to get current element  and in jquery we can use `$(this)` to get the same. So, after knowing that everything else was easy.Just remember some of the commonly use methods in jquery .